# Weird looking page after refreshing

Tags: html, asp.net, layout

I often encounter this issue when refreshing and browsing my asp.net website.

(I covered some of the information that was visible in the pictures below.)

Before Refreshing:
[image: Before refreshing]

After refreshing:
[image: After Refreshing]

This also happens when I navigate to a new page, but just like I mentioned before, it doesn't happen all the time but it does happen regularly.

I've added some Jquery to try and fix this but the problem remains.

```
 $(window).bind("resize", function () {
                $("#content").width($(window).width() - 16);
            });
```

Also tried this code just to make sure the DOM is ready.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
                $(window).bind("resize", function () {
                    $("#content").width($(window).width() - 16);
                });
            });
```

**UPDATE:**

I've fixed the content `div` by setting it's `max-width` to 980 pixels, the navigation menu is still leaving it's intended position. If anyone can provide an answer as to why this happened it would be appreciated, this `max-width` thing seems like a bit of a lazy hack because although it fixes the div's width it's a solution for a problem which shouldn't be happening in the first place.

These two pictures show the current problem.

Before refreshing:
[image]

After refreshing:
[image]

Comment: one reason may be that a JavaScript function that manage the dimensions of tables and divs is triggered before document.ready. Also error log window may help to find external resources like CSS files which failed to load.

Comment: You should check the console through firebug or the developer tools in order to see if there is an error.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: if you use UpdatePanel look if you update part of the page and need more, or you do not run some javascript after. At the end look for html errors, probably you have forget some tags open.

Comment: I don't use UpdatePanel.

Comment: do you use the AjaxControlToolkit?

Comment: its properly because of a open tag

Comment: I'm not using AJAX at all.